# Can "to revolve around" mean "to deal with/pertain to"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrasing

```
... around which the book revolves.
```

Can I use this expression to say that the book is dealing with a subject, addressing an issue, or talking about something?

I'm open to suggestions if there is a better way to put it.

Comment: Wonder where's there research behind this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use *[revolve](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revolve)* this way; it would be used to mean:

> **5.** to focus or center on.

It's a figurative usage.  *Revolve around [something]* in its original physical sense means to *move in a circular orbit around [something]*.  Applying the word outside the physical domain still brings to mind the physical connotation of orbiting, demonstrating that the topic is to the book as the sun is to a planet.